# How to properly replace an input action in unitys input system

Tags: unity, c#

I'm currently running into some unintended behaviour when using Unity's input system. I currently have a state machine for my player controls, so theres a move state, dash state, wall slide state and so on. I would like to enable/disable/modify the users controls based on what state theyre in. My example now is, in the movestate when you press X on a ps4 controller the `jump()` method should be called. In the wall slide state if you press X the `wallJump()` method should be called. However, right now, I'm getting unintend behaviours where both methods are called regardless of what state Im in when I press the X button.

Here is my layout for the code:

```
    public MoveState(PlayerSM _playerSM, Animator animator, Transform playerTransform, Transform cam, AnimationCurve accelCurve, ref PlayerControls controls, ref CharacterController controller, ref Vector2 move, float walkSpeed, float runSpeed, float turnSmoothVelocity, float turnSmoothTime, LayerMask layer, PhysicsHelper helper ){
                playerSM = _playerSM;
               
                this.animator = animator;
                this.playerTransform = playerTransform;
                this.cam = cam;
                this.accelCurve = accelCurve;
                this.controls = controls;
                this.controller = controller;
                this.move = move;
                this.walkSpeed = walkSpeed;
                this.runSpeed = runSpeed;
                this.turnSmoothVelocity = turnSmoothVelocity;
                this.turnSmoothTime = turnSmoothTime;
                this.layer = layer;
                this.helper = helper;
            }
            public void Enter()
            {
                controls.Gameplay.Enable(); 
                velocity = new Vector2();
                move = new Vector2();
                controls.Gameplay.Move.performed += ctx => move = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
                controls.Gameplay.Move.canceled  += ctx => move = Vector2.zero;
                controls.Gameplay.Jump.started += ctx => Jump();
                controls.Gameplay.Jump.canceled += ctx => jumpButtonHeld = false;
            // //     controls.Gameplay.Slide.started += ctx => sliding = true;
            // //     controls.Gameplay.Slide.canceled += ctx => sliding = false;
            //     controls.Gameplay.Dash.performed += ctx => InitiateDash();
            //     controls.Gameplay.Enable();
                velocity = playerSM.getVelocity();
                controls.Gameplay.Jump.Dispose();
                controls.Gameplay.Enable(); 
                
    
            }
    
            public void Exit()
            {
                playerSM.setVelocity(velocity);
                controls.Gameplay.Move.Dispose();
                controls.Gameplay.Jump.Dispose();
                controls.Gameplay.Disable();
            }
    
            public void FixedTick()
            {
                
            }
    
            public void Tick(){
             //unimportant movement code
    
    
    
                if(helper.checkPos(playerTransform.position + Vector3.up * controller.height/2 + playerTransform.forward*5,1f,layer))playerSM.ChangeState(playerSM.wallSlide);
               
                //player is on a slope, disable the controls so they cant slide down the slope
                //check to see if they're on the ground too before disabling controls as onSlope flag could trigger when standing in front of slope D:
                    
              //more code unimportant to this question
            }


Now here is my wall slide state:



public void Enter(){
          
            normal = new Vector3();
            Debug.Log("Wall Slide STATE");
            velocity = playerSM.getVelocity();
            controls.Enable();
            controls.Gameplay.Jump.performed += ctx => wallJump();
        }

        public void Exit(){
            velocity = Vector3.zero;
            controls.Gameplay.Jump.Dispose();
            controls.Disable();
            playerSM.setVelocity(velocity);
        }

        public void FixedTick(){
        }

        public void Tick(){
            RaycastHit hit = helper.getHitInfo(playerTransform.position + Vector3.up * controller.height/2,playerTransform.forward,5);
            velocity = helper.applyGravity(velocity,false);
            if(helper.checkPos(groundCheck.position,0.1f,layer) || hit.collider == null){
                 playerSM.ChangeState(playerSM.moveState);
                // velocity = Vector3.zero;
                playerSM.setVelocity(velocity);
            }else{
                normal = hit.normal;
                Debug.DrawRay(hit.point,hit.normal*5 + Vector3.up*25,Color.black,2f);    
            }
            controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }

       


        public void wallJump(){
            Debug.Log("Wall jump");
        }
    }
```

I've been trying to read the unity documentation for this input system but it seems kinda verbose. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use several Action Maps (the left most column  in the input system window). Then different state actions subscribe to input actions from their intended action map. When your player swaps states you enable/disable the related action map.

Comment: Thats such a simple idea thank you so much! I really appreciate it!